# How do I do this in jQuery and CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am new to jQuery, I have used it and played and around with it for galleries and sliders.

I want to add [this type of menu](http://www.mbusa.com/mercedes/index?utm_expid=62343809-0) on my website (the middle one with 4 boxes).

I need to be able to have expanding `div`s. At first it shows just the picture, but when you hover the `div` expands upwards and shows the picture and the text that accompanies it.

I can figure out most things but this has got me stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: An expanding div height with overflow hidden? That site in particular just expands the div with a gray background and then fades in the full view.

Comment: can you help me with an example?? I dont understand css to that extreme with hidden and overflow.. Those are concepts im still attemping to wrap my mind around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've built you a very basic jsFiddle to help you get the idea, I've kept it simple so you can understand and build upon it.
http://jsfiddle.net/FF3jc/4/

In the JS section, all that's really happening is, when you hover over, a new class is getting applied, then hover off, it's getting removed.

You can use this class that is added/removed to control the height/styling as you wish.

Edit, fixed the jsfiddle, included the wrong one - d'oh.

Comment: I can create simple CSS dropdowns. I guess where im stumped, is i want the moxes to expand upward not downward? Im sure its a CSS thing.. and i bet it has to do positioning, im just not sure..

Can you point me??

Comment: Created a new jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FF3jc/12/
See how you can just add different CSS styles to achieve whatever you want really, in this case I've just given it padding-top, and a minus margin-top.

Comment: I have got it working?? Now im curious if you know how to make the content in the div to shift up?

http://www.designedbyjackie.com/playground/testme.html

In the link above the word text and image stay stationary but doesnt move up when the div is moused over..

Is there a way to do this??

Comment: As usual, another jsfiddle :D.
http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/FF3jc/14/
See I've just switched it from padding-top, to padding-bottom? Everything is very simple when you can just think of a way of doing it ;).

Comment: Perfect... Thank you so much... I didnt even think of padding bottom

Answer (score 2):

This site uses jQuery Hero Carousel. It is explained here. http://www.paulwelsh.info/jquery-plugins/hero-carousel/

My apologies. Although this site has a download for hero-carousel it has no explanation. It would appear that half the web is devoted to jquery carousels.

Comment: I know its a carousel, or maybe even an accordian type of thing. However i have scoured the internet looking for something that makes the div (image) expand upwards upon mouseover